# Expected scalar type Double but found Float

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

I am getting this error while trying to give an input image batch to my Pytorch model

`"RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 4, 4], expected input[5, 96, 96, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 96 channels instead".`

I read images with skimage. My images are 96x96 and batch size is 5. Here is my Generator class:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    def downsample(input_filters, output_filters, normalize=True):
      layers = [nn.Conv2d(input_filters, output_filters, kernel_size=4, padding=1, stride=2)]

      if normalize:
        layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(output_filters, 0.8))
      
      layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))

      return layers
    
    def upsample(input_filters, output_filters, normalize=True, last_layer=False):
      layers = [nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_filters, output_filters, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)]

      if normalize:
        layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(output_filters, 0.8))

      if not last_layer:
        layers.append(nn.ReLU())

      return layers
    
    self.model = nn.Sequential(
        *downsample(3, 64, normalize=False), # 96x96
        *downsample(64, 64), # 48x48
        *downsample(64, 128), # 24x24
        *downsample(128, 256), # 12x12
        *downsample(256, 512), # 6x6
        nn.Conv2d(512, 4000, kernel_size=4), # 3x3
        *upsample(4000, 512), # 6x6
        *upsample(512, 256), # 12x12
        *upsample(256, 128), # 24x24
        *upsample(128, 64), # 48x48
        *upsample(64, 64), # 96x96
        *upsample(64, 3, last_layer=True), # 192x192
        nn.Tanh()
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.model(x)
```

Here is my Dataset Class:

```
class OutpaintDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, data_path, input_size, output_size):
    self.data_path = data_path
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.image_names = glob.glob(data_path)

  def outpaint(self, image):
    masked = image
    mask_size = int(self.input_size/2)

    masked[:, :mask_size, :] = 1
    masked[:, -1*mask_size:, :] = 1
    masked[:mask_size, :, :] = 1
    masked[-1*mask_size:, :, :] = 1

    return masked

  def custom_resize(self, image, size):
    return transform.resize(image, (size, size))
  
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.image_names)
  
  def __getitem__(self, index):
      image = io.imread(self.image_names[index])
      
      # image to size of (96, 96)
      input_image = self.custom_resize(image, self.input_size)
      
      # image to size of (192, 192)
      ground_image = self.custom_resize(image, self.output_size)
      masked_image = self.outpaint(image=ground_image.copy())

      return input_image, masked_image, ground_image
```

### --UPDATE--

I changed the shape of the given image batch from torch.Size([5, 192, 192, 3]) to torch.Size([5, 3, 192, 192]). Now I am getting a new error **RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float**.

I reshape and use my images at the following code block

```
for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
  input_image, masked_image, ground_image, = data

  reshaped = masked_image.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
  reshaped = reshaped.type(torch.double)

  output = generator(reshaped)
  break
```

I used io and transform functions from skimage

Answer (score 0):

I usually print model summary using torchinfo library to debug such errors.
Your input should be in the form of [5, 3, 192, 192].
If image size is 96x96, your image size before applying the convolution is less than 4x4 so it shows error.
[this image will show you image size after each of layer with number of parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ott4L.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I give 192x192 input batch I got a similar error such RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 4, 4], expected input[5, 192, 192, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 192 channels instead

Comment: Input are organized in [N, C, W, H] format. So your input tensor should be of the shape   [5, 3, 192, 192] and not [5, 192, 192, 3]

Comment: I tried the following code but I got "expected scalar type Double but found Float" error

`inp = input_image.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
inp = inp.type(torch.double)
generator(inp)`

inp.type() command gives torch.DobuleTensor

Comment: I updated my question you can find the necessary code blocks